# jQuery autocomplete origin

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm adding autocomplete on several inputs at the same time, thus writing a single handling function as the source. I'd like to have the id attribute of the origin (the input that triggered the action) available in my handling function. But it seems there's no direct reference to it within autocomplete...

```
$('#inputForm #supplier, #inputForm #label').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.post("autocomplete.php", {id: ???, term: request.term}, success);
    }
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried `this.id`?  I don't know if that will get you the right "this" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to Richard ;)

```
 $(this.element).attr('id')
```

Complete code, in case anyone would be interested:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.post("autocomplete.php", {origin: $(this.element).attr('id'), term: request.term}, success);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

I suggest you also use a class for all your autocomplete like for example

```
.autocomplete
```

and add data- for your extra data like

```
data-id, data-url
```

you can get the value of data-xxx attributes by using

```
$(this).data('id') and $(this).data('url')
enter code here
$(".autocomplete")
.each(function () {
   $(this).autocomplete({
      source : function(request, response) {
    $.post($(this).data('url'), {origin: $(this.).data('id'), term:               request.term}, success);
}
       });
    });
```